# Can't run Java program from Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I recently created and compiled a Java program, but it will not run from the Terminal. It isn't the program, because it WILL run from Eclipse. This is what I get from Terminal when I attempt to run the program:

```
Grants-MBP:~ Grant$ java /Users/Grant/Desktop/Pythagorean
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/Grant/Desktop/Pythagorean
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.Grant.Desktop.Pythagorean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Call `java` from the base of your package structure and only reference the package name seperated by `.` characters. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433366/running-java-in-package-from-command-line

Answer (score 2):

navigate to the desktop folder

```
cd /Users/Grant/Desktop/
```

invoke java using

```
java Pythagorean
```