# How to share symbols in java?

Tags: java, java-7, javac, importerror

I have two java programs (classes), both in a directory called java_weirdness.

Here they are below :

## MyClass

```
package java_weirdness;
public class MyClass{
    public int num;
    public MyClass(int initialNum) {
        num = initialNum;
    }
}
```

## MyLauncher

```
package java_weirdness;

public class MyLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass new_member = new MyClass(3);
    }
}
```

When I compile `MyLauncher.java`, I get the following errors, even though I clearly imported it:

```
MyLauncher.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass new_member = new MyClass(3);
        ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class MyLauncher
MyLauncher.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass new_member = new MyClass(3);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class MyLauncher
2 errors
```

What is the proper way to access `MyClass` while in `MyLauncher`? Thank you.

Comment: have you compiled first `MyClass`?

Comment: To start with I suggest you use an IDE which will set up and build your project for you.  You have enough to learn without struggling with the tools.

Comment: Compiled both.  `javac MyClass.java` compiles fine.   `javac MyLauncher.java` is what gives the error.    Using Sublime.

Comment: You will need to set `-cp` in the `java` command to that `MyClass` is in the class path of `MyLauncher` during run time. And Sublime is a text editor, not an IDE.

Comment: Something else I noticed.. You are calling ` MyClass new_member = new myClass(3);` that needs to be  MyClass new_member = new MyClass(3);

Comment: @NicholasRobinson that's the output maybe of a previous javac

Comment: @AlexGreg I can see that's the output, not sure what you are telling me.

Comment: typos....really sorry guys.  they're all `MyClass`.

Comment: Maybe there's an import I'm missing?

Comment: Are the classes in the same project?

Comment: Yeah.  I mean, they're in the same directory `java_weirdness`, and the class files are in the same directory too:  `MyClass.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go up one directory then do

```
javac java_weirdness/*.java
```

and after

```
java java_weirdness.MyLauncher
```

form more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369055/3548826)

PS: we're too much IDE dependent xD

Comment: weird, so you have to compile the entire package?

Comment: try to remove the package declaration and it will work on your way

Comment: Don't get too much into the habit of omitting the package declaration. For any serious software this is "bad style", in particular: classes in the "default package" (if a package declaration is missing) cannot be made visible to classes within a proper package. The Java Language Specification even allows different default packages which creates further confusion ... so, take it as convenience for smallest toy applications only. -- OTOH, even with packages you can compile classes one at a time, provided required classes have already been compiled, the point is to include the package name.