# Purpose of setting PATH variable for Java

Tags: java

I'm a complete noob and have been trying to set my mac to learn Java. I have installed JDK 10.0.1 and eclipse oxygen. I also successfully edited the `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to my jdk location using this:
[Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable on MAC OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9)

So far so good, I was able to run simple programs both on eclipse and on terminal ( was having trouble for a while because I couldn't run "HelloWorld" from terminal as it was under a separate package) after using the top answer from [Running java in package from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433366/running-java-in-package-from-command-line/19433387#19433387?newreg=e35f947b2d78482b88847adf3f3d67b99)

However my friend later told me that if I wanted to run java programs from terminal, I'd need to edit `PATH` variable as it was where the os looks for executables. A lot of websites mentioned editing `PATH` as well. I ran `echo $PATH` and terminal outputted `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`.

So I'm really confused that if I haven't edit `PATH`, then why am i able to run commands like `java` or `javac` from terminal? The `/usr/bin` folder has `java` `javac` `javadoc` etc aliases inside it, could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! Do the aliases come with the OS or are they added during jdk installation?

Comment: @catsRjerks some aliases come with the OS, and when you install the jdk, those java aliases are then added.

Comment: @davedwards that makes sense. Thank you.