# Finding Main Class in "Hello World" program in Java

Tags: java, class

I have a seemingly simple program in Java, but when I run it, I get the error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class**

Here is my code.

```
public class HelloPrinter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I'm entirely new to the Java language, and I don't know what else to do. My program file is named "hello_world.java", and when attempting to run the program, I type in "java hello_world.java". Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I've also attempted "java -cp hello_world", but that gave me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong? Impossible to say, since you didn't tell us how you compile and run your code.

Comment: This error is very, very common. Please google it

Comment: How are you executing your app?

Comment: I used a text editor to write the program, saved it as .java file, and ran it using the terminal application on a mac. What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Your certainly executing another .class file than `HelloPrinter.class`

Comment: Dup: [How to execute a java .class from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1279542)

Comment: I'm entirely new to the Java language, and I don't know what else to do. My program file is named "hello_world.java", and when attempting to run the program, I type in "java hello_world.java". Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I've also attempted "java -cp hello_world", but that gave me the same error.

Comment: The file must be named HelloPrinter.java if the class is HelloPrinter. See linked question.

Comment: I renamed the file to HelloPrinter.java as you recommended, but I'm still getting the same error. **Error: Could not find or load main class HelloPrinter.java**

Comment: Just read the duplicate question.

Comment: I have read it, and I still do not understand what needs to be done. I ran "javac HelloPrinter.java" and received a new file called "HelloPrinter.class". Even after reading the duplicate question, I still do no understand what needs to be done. What obvious mistake am I making?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what little information you've given, I'd say you're executing it the wrong way.

Make sure you run the following two commands:

```
javac HelloPrinter.java
java HelloPrinter
```

The first command [compiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) your source code into a [.class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) file. The second command executes that class file.

Comment: This works. That was the fundamental, obvious mistake I was making. I'm new to this, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jacob Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it helped you.