# Execute java code with spring dependencies before JMeter test

Tags: java, spring, testing, jmeter, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to do some stress tests on an API with JMeter. I have two environments (QA and production) and I want to set up QA's database before running JMeter tests.

I can't use JDBC or MongoDB configuration elements because it's a cloud database (DynamoDB - AmazonWS). I thought about using raw requests with API-token to AmazonWS's API but I'd prefer to use a Java class I already have (a class that create-delete queries to cloud DB) but it has Spring dependencies.

I know that with JMeter I can run some Java code but I don't know how to run classes with Spring dependencies like a BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best option would be to use

- [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) with 1 virtual user and 1 iteration

  - [OS Process Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) to execute your class (see [How to execute a java .class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line) for example)

Running class from JMeter using i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) is also possible but you will need to

- have all the dependencies in JMeter's classpath
- ensure that there are no conflicts between JMeter and your class dependency libraries