# Maven: using command line to run a java class file

Tags: java, maven

I have a java project build using Maven "quickstart" template. The structure looks like

```
src
  main
    java
      myapp
        HelloWorld.java
```

The HelloWorld.java is declared to be under package "myapp"

inside pom.xml, only junit is included.

Now, after I run maven compile, I get a class file under

```
target
  classes
    myapp
      HelloWorld.class
```

but after I cd to target/classes/myapp, and do

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

I get NoClassDefFoundError, i did it according to [How to execute a java .class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line)

I tried

```
java -cp . myapp.HelloWorld    (myapp is the package)
```

I still get "could not find or load main class"

My question is: I set the classpath using "-cp .", then why i still can't run the class? does it has anything to do with Maven?

I know I don't need to use command line, I am just curious.

Comment: I assume that you need to specify the package name - i.e. go to target/classes and run `java -cp . myapp.HelloWorld`

Comment: @PetterFriberg, I read all those questions, but the solutions not work for me, that's why I ask this question, and I knew it has a high change to get downvote because of that. I just want someone to take 3 minutes to reproduce it, I am really frustrated over this seemed simple question..

Comment: The problem is like in the linked question: you need to be careful with the package declaration. `HelloWorld` is a class under the `myapp` package. So to run it, you **must not** `cd` into `myapp`. You should `cd` to the root folder which is `target/classes` here and invoke `java myapp\HelloWorld`. That said, it would be preferable for you to make a JAR out of your project (which Maven creates under `target` by default), `cd` to the basedir and launch the jar with `java -jar target\name-of-jar.jar`

Comment: @Tunaki, your suggestion works, but could you explain why java -cp . works here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-cp . indicates to Java that you want it to look in the current directory for classes. To make this work, you'd need to use:

```
java -cp target/classes myapp.HelloWorld
```

(Note that "myapp" is the package that your HelloWorld class is defined in, and is declared on the first line of your class, as

```
package myapp;
```

)

By using the above java command, you don't need to cd into the target/classes/myapp directory. If you want to cd into target/classes, you can use the following command instead:

```
java -cp . myapp.HelloWorld
```

UPDATE: Sample Project Contents:

```
app/
app/pom.xml
app/src/
app/src/main/
app/src/main/java/
app/src/main/java/myapp/
app/src/main/java/myapp/HelloWorld.java
```

after running mvn clean install, the structure changes to:

```
app/
app/pom.xml
app/src/
app/src/main/
app/src/main/java/
app/src/main/java/myapp/
app/src/main/java/myapp/HelloWorld.java
app/target/
app/target/classes/
app/target/classes/test-1.0.0.jar
app/target/classes/myapp/
app/target/classes/myapp/HelloWorld.class
```

After compiling, I was able to cd to app/target/classes, and run java -cp . myapp.HelloWorld

If you're still having trouble, can you post your sample class and pom.xml?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I mean, in theory it should work, but I guess it has to do with maven. Could you create a simple project and try it?

Comment: java -cp target/classes myapp.HelloWorld    works, but after i cd and then use java -cp . myapp.HelloWorld , it can't load main class

Comment: Where did you cd to? I just ran through a sample application, and updated my answer with the project's the structure.

Comment: I knew what concept I got wrong, I cd into the most inner directory. Since my java file is put under a package, I shouldn't do that. Thank you!