# Compile Java program on Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

I have tried to compile a java program (hello.java) on Cygwin.

> $ javac hello.java

I got the java class file named A.class.
How can I get an output class file named hello.class?

Please understand my question! I am not asking how to compile a java program in a command line. Indeed, I already did it. But I got the java class file named A.class instead of hello.class. So, please read my question again. Thanks!

Comment: Try `java hello`

Comment: Do you actually have a class called `hello` in hello.java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a java .class from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line)

Comment: your hello.java file should have `public Hello` class declaration in it

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Please read my question again!

Comment: I am not asking how to execute a java .class from the command line. Is someone able to answer my question?

Answer (score -1):

I am going to answer my own question. 
javac hello.java > hello.class