# Error in "java HelloWorld" after compiling

Tags: java, git-bash

I am a beginner and am setting up my java on windows 10 following the instruction of [cs61b](http://fa20.datastructur.es/materials/lab/lab1setup/lab1setup)

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello world!");
     }
}
```

After I compiled it with `javac HelloWorld.java`, I ran `java HelloWorld` but it reported an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

Instead, `java HelloWorld.java` works. I wonder how to fix that problem? Thanks!

[image: Here is the screenshot of the problem shown on my Git Bash]

Comment: What is the content of your CLASSPATH setting/variable?

Comment: My class path is: %JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar    The JAVA_HOME variable is C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.2.12-hotspot\

Comment: I install Java by installing Java OpenJDK 14 (HotSpot JVM). AndI just notice that I have already Java 12 in my windows 10. Should I uninstall Java 12?

Answer (score 2):

Try `java -cp . HelloWorld`. With compiled files you have to specify the classpath where your classes are. Then you tell the class where your `main` method is.

The `java HelloWorld.java` is working because you are probably using Java 11+

[How to execute a java .class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I I installed Java OpenJDK 14 (with HotSpot JVM) and I think 'javac HelloWorld' should work, as the bottom of this instruction page shows [link](http://fa20.datastructur.es/materials/lab/lab1setup/lab1setup). I don't know what caused my problem.  I just notice that I have a Java 12 previously installed in my computer. Is that a possible cause?

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved when I add ".;" in the beginning of the CLASSPATH. Thanks!