# java JDK 1.8.0 Win 11 - system variables

Tags: java, path, classpath

I've just istalled JDK8 on PC Windows 11 Home
Now im trying to run simple default program from NetBeans14

**In environmental variables:**

PATH : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

CLASSPATH : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

**Project build on hard disk**
C:\Projects\Hello\src\main\java\pack\hello

1. on cmd going tn cd C:\Projects\Hello\src\main\java\pack\hello
2. javac compiles .java file on .class file
3. command "java Hello" output: *Error: Could not find or load main class Hello*
   Hello.class is there.

checking commands, all works:

java

javac

javac -version

Please to support, or send some similar problems posts.
All web answers are speaking about setting PATH and CLASSPATH, where in my case it already took place.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: “CLASSPATH : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin” is incorrect.  The classpath a series of locations where Java programs exist.  It should *never* point to a location inside a Java installation.  You probably want to set CLASSPATH to `C:\Projects\Hello\target\classes`, if your project is a Maven project.

Comment: I think you would face this issue due to not considering the package in **compilation** or in **execution** Follow this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: CLASSPATH changing on directory with class -not working

considering package running using "java" - not working

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your steps. I downloaded and installed the newest JDK 8 on Windows 11, and NetBeans 14.

Then I looked through the Environment Variables, and the only mention of Java was in the system Path variable:

[image]

You see, I have no CLASSPATH variable, nor haven't I manually set anything. Everything was installed automatically. I have no explicit path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_... in my Path variable.

And I created a simple app in NetBeans. It runs *from NetBeans* successfully. Just do "Run Project" (F6) in the NetBeans interface.

If you need to run it *from the command line* for some reason, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line) may help.

If you need to run it on another computer, I would advise you not to do it with cmd. Compile it into jar, then wrap it into exe (in case of Windows) using launch4J.

Comment: even with setting only PATH on this value - not working

in fact yes, but then i need the other person to run the other project im doing on his/her PC using cmd

Comment: thank you @Bartek for the details, see my edit above then